# How to hide a collapsible toolbar on a drawing mobile application?

Tags: mobile, toolbar, graphic-design

While in fullscreen mode when the user taps a button on one corner of the screen, a small toolbar with a row of buttons appears. The buttons are not related to how the drawing should work, like for instance the brush size or color, but rather they activate some utility related functions, like for instance screen capture or light vs dark theme for the canvas background.

**Normal mode**

[image]

**Toolbar activated**

[image]

1) Since the area of the screen where the expanded toolbar appears occludes a significant part of the canvas, should the toolbar collapse to the normal mode after it's been open if the user starts interacting with the canvas?

2) If the user starts interacting with the canvas, should this action only hide the expanded toolbar without doing some drawing on the canvas, or should the canvas immediately start drawing in response to the user action.

3) Should tapping on the canvas be treated differently from dragging when number 2 happens? For instant only hide the toolbar if tapping on the canvas vs start drawing if the user drags the touch on the canvas.

By tapping on the screen I mean to touch and stop touching the screen without dragging the finger.

Answer (score 1):

1) I believe it should. Any interaction that is repetitive and has no significant advantages could be removed. Is there any reason you wouldn't have it auto-collapse? It will reduce the user input and for canvas style applications, keeping the user on the canvas as much as possible should be a key goal. This will help them get back to working.

2) Again, I think it should start the action once it has been clicked, otherwise users will be clicking twice to exit which to me seems like repetitive/unnecessary behavior.

3) This might just be personal preference, but I would expect and appreciate it exiting as soon as any click is registered, not just a drag.

The basis of my answers comes from the fact that the toolbar is for utilities, and so users know precisely what they want to do when they open the toolbar, and once they are done, will want to quickly return to their work on the canvas area.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the value of an adaptive toolbar.

Keep a counter of the number of times the user re-opens the toolbar.  If that number exceeds X (3?) within a window of time T (15 seconds?) then keep the toolbar open for D (90?) seconds.

Trial several ranges with power-users, or go to a local meetup where you can find people who would use this kind of app.

With some experimentation, you can find a set of variables that feels *cognitively ergonomic*.

Answer (score 1):

1. It may be that the user needs to return to that toolbar often. If
   the toolbar is for something like Color, I can see an argument for leaving it open.
2. I don't think it is clear that the toolbar should
   collapse. If the user has the ability to pinch-to-zoom and pan the canvas the toolbar may not get in the way.
3. Tap to dismiss the toolbar could be an interesting interaction.